# Subscript under sum with dot

Tags: subscripts

I have a problem with the subscript under a sum with dot, it changes the position of the subscript. Namely,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 \dot{\sum}_{i \in I}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

places the subscript next to the sum instead of under it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you executing the command in inline or display-style math mode?

Comment: Added the complete document. It was in the align environment (so not inline).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using an accent upon `\sum` makes it lose the nature of operator. You simply have to reinstate it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\dotsum}{\mathop{\dot\sum}}

\begin{document}
\[
 \dotsum_{i \in I}
 \sum_{i \in I}
\]
\end{document}
```

The `\sum` next to `\dotsum` is just for checking the alignment.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
 \begin{align}
  \sum\limits^{\text{\textbullet}}_{i \in I}
 \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. The dot above the sum is only a bit to high.